# Credit Card Swipe in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, credit-card

I am using Javascript to get the credit card information from Magentic Strip Reader device. (I am using USB attached device)

I have written a code in HTML Javascript but it failed to run. I mean my page is on HTTPS when I connected the device after opening this page. The device lights turns to green which means this page is security proof.

But when I swipe the card it did not show nothing in the field. I also have a function to focus on the field. But I don't know whats wrong it, Please see my code below and give me any suggestions.

HTML:

```
<span style='required'>*</span> - Indicates required field.
   <div class='fields'>Swiped Information</div>
     <input type=text name='swiped' id='swiped'>

   <div class='fields'>First Name</div>
    <input type=text name='first_name' id='first_name'><span style='required'>*</span>
   </div>
   <div class='fields'>Last Name</div>
    <input type=text name='last_name' id='last_name'><span style='required'>*</span>
   </div>
   <div class='fields'>Expiration</div>
    <input type=text size=8 name='expiration' id='expiration'><span style='required'>*</span>(MMYY)
   </div>
   <div class='fields'>CVV Code</div>
    <input type=text size=8 name='cvv' id='cvv'><span style='required'>*</span>
   </div>
   <div class='fields'>Credit Card Number</div>
    <input type=text name='card' id='card'><span style='required'>*</span>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <div class='buttons'></div>
    <a onclick="readCard();" style="cursor:pointer; color:red;">Swipe Credit Card</a>
   </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readCard () {

   document.getElementById('swiped').focus();



  var card_data = document.getElementById('swiped').value;

   if(card_data != ''){


var details1 = card_data.split("^");

var card_number = details1[0];
card_number = card_number.substring(2);

var names = details1[1].split("/");
var first_name = names[1];
var last_name = names[0];

var details2 = details1[2].split(";");
details2 = details2[1].split("=");

var exp_date = details2[1];
exp_date = exp_date.substring(0, exp_date.length - 1);
exp_date = exp_date.substring(2, 3) + "/" + exp_date.substring(0,2);

document.getElementById('card').value = card_number;
document.getElementById('first_name').value = first_name;
document.getElementById('last_name').value = last_name;
document.getElementById('expiration').value = exp_date;
   }

}
</script>
```

Comment: I can't imagine JavaScript can access a USB device. You sure you're not missing a vendor plugin for the browser?

Comment: Hey Brad,

I am new to Credit Card Swipe thing. I am using Magtek Credit card reader

http://www.magtek.com/v2/products/secure-card-reader-authenticators/mini.asp

And I dont know that there must be a plugin to communicate the device and browser?  Can you please help?

Comment: Have you checked out their [demo programs](http://www.magtek.com/support/software/demo_programs/)? Looks like they have OCX controls to tie things up.

Comment: @brad. Yes I checked one of those but it is hard to run, but now I will check each and every one of it. Thanks Man for your help

Comment: Does this work if you just simply focus on the field and swipe the card (with no JavaScript)?

Answer (score 0):

If the swiper model is IDMB, then it is not encrypted but may be set to HID and not KBE (keyboard emulated). Are you able to swipe into a text editor, notepad? If not, you may be able to switch it from HID to KBE with MagTek's demo application.

http://www.magtek.com/support/software/demo_programs/usb_swipe_insert.asp